# Login using java jsoup doesn't work on site rotowire

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

After trying several tutorials and reading many posts here, I still can't access the Rotowire site. This is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    String loginFormUrl = "https://www.rotowire.com/users/login.php";
            String loginActionUrl = "https://www.rotowire.com/users/login.php";
    HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {

                Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl)

                        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                        .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                        .timeout(10 * 1000)
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .execute();
                cookies.putAll(loginForm.cookies()); 
                String username = "****";
                String password = "****";
                formData.put("username",username);
                formData.put("password",password);
                formData.put("landingPage", "/");

                Connection.Response homePage = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
                        .cookies(cookies)
                        .data(formData)
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                        .timeout(10 * 1000)
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .execute();
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl).cookies(homePage.cookies()).get();
                System.out.println(doc.html());
    } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                enter code heree.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do not use JSoup for login actions, since it does not handle javascript. Maybe you should move to [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) or [Selenium](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html) to accomplish what you need.

EDIT: Adding an example using HtmlUnit

```
public void Login(String pass, String user) {
        try {
            HtmlPage p = navegador.getPage("https://www.somewebsite.com"); //The login webpage
            HtmlForm form = p.getFormByName("form-login"); //The login form name
            form.getInputByName("UserName").setValueAttribute(user);  //Setting username to the form
            form.getInputByName("Password").setValueAttribute(pass);  //Setting password to the form
            p = form.getInputByValue("Go").click(); //Clicking the form button by its input value and getting the next page
            System.out.println(p.asText()); //printing the page after being logged in
        }catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The `navegador` object is an instance of `WebClient`, which you can instantiate doing something like:

```
WebClient navegador = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
```

Comment: I did some testing with HtmlUnit, but it doesn't work the same.

Comment: @Cloud10 if this is the case, then Selenium is your best shot. But I believe HtmlUnit should work. I will edit my answer, with an example, in which Login works fine for me.